# Pesicha of 3 Sifrei Torah: special time

Tags: jewish-books, chanuka, sefer-torah

Someone sent me a voice recording of someone mentioning an idea from the Sefer Heichalos that when there is we open 3 sifrei Torah (Torah scrolls, on shabbas – chanuka – rosh chodesh), then there is a entrance in Heaven that opens up and is a very opportune time for salvation.  He also mentions that the Pnei Menachem (of Ger?) would mention this to people. Does anyone know where this is found in the sefer Heichalos?

Comment: I'd like to see this mentioning. This year, you will have the good fortune of seeing 2 such opportunities in the same year. It will occur again on Shabbat Rosh Hodesh Parshat Hahodesh as well. Incidentally, such occurences are somewhat frequent.

Comment: @DanF 3.  Simchas Torah happens every year.